# Contact Management System in C

Tags: c

It's only my second code in C so far. I've some knowledge about this language, dynamic memory allocation etc. but I'm still far to be good in it. Earlier I used to program in Java, so I could have passed some habits from there. In general - what should I change to make this code somehow more perfect, what I shouldn't do and what practices should be cultivated by me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BASE_DECIMAL 10
#define ID_LENGTH 5
#define MAX_FNAME_LENGTH 16
#define MAX_SNAME_LENGTH 32
#define MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH 15
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
//colors
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

//prototypes
char* inputFirstName();
char* inputSurname();
char* inputPhoneNumber();
bool searchDuplicatedNumber( FILE *fp, char* search_Number );
char* checkConditions( FILE *fp );
char* ordinals( int i );
char* generateID();
FILE *checkInAllContacts();
void addNewContact( char* path, FILE *allContacts );
void addToAllContacts( char* path );
void showContactBasedOnPath( char* path );

int main( int argC, char* argV[] ) {
    
    //declare
    char* id;
    char option;
    char* path_to_specific_file;

    //allocate
    id = malloc(ID_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    path_to_specific_file = malloc(ID_LENGTH * sizeof(char));

    //check
    if( id == NULL || path_to_specific_file == NULL) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed" );
        return 0;
    }
    
    do{

    printf(     "\n\t\t***Contact management system***\n1. Add new contact\n2. Show all contacts\n3. Show specific contact\n*Press 'q' to exit*\n"      );
    fgets( &option, 3, stdin );
    
    //assign
    id = generateID();
    
    //MENU
    switch(option) {
        
        case '1':
            addNewContact(id, checkInAllContacts());
            fclose(checkInAllContacts());
            addToAllContacts(id);
            free(id);
            break;

        case '2':
            showContactBasedOnPath("All_Contacts.txt");
            break;

        case '3': //I know it can be probably achieved in different way
            do{
                puts( "Input path to file(based on given id!): ");
                fgets( path_to_specific_file, (ID_LENGTH + 1), stdin );
                showContactBasedOnPath(path_to_specific_file);
            }while((getchar()) != '\n');
            
            free(path_to_specific_file);
            break;
        
        case 'q':
            printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED   "\nExiting...\n"   ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
            exit(0);

        default:
            puts( "Undefined option!" );
            break;
    }
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}

//functions-----------------------

char* inputFirstName() {
    
    char* name;
    name = (char*) malloc( MAX_FNAME_LENGTH * sizeof(char) );
    
    if( name == NULL ) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - inputFirstName" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    printf( "\n\n%s: ", "First name" );
    fgets( name, MAX_FNAME_LENGTH, stdin );
    return name;
}

char* inputSurname() {
        
    char* sName;
    sName = (char*) malloc( MAX_SNAME_LENGTH * sizeof(char) );

    if( sName == NULL ) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - inputSurname" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    printf( "\n%s: ", "Surname");
    fgets( sName, MAX_SNAME_LENGTH, stdin );
    return sName;
}


//phone number functions
char* inputPhoneNumber() {
    
    char* phoneNumber;
    phoneNumber = (char*) malloc( MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH * sizeof(char) );
    
    if( phoneNumber == NULL ) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - inputPhoneNumber" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf( "\n%s: ", "Phone number" );
    fgets( phoneNumber, MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH, stdin );
    return phoneNumber;
}
//search for duplicates
bool searchDuplicatedNumber(FILE *fp, char* search_Number) {
    
    char* properties = (char*) malloc( BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char) );

    if( properties == NULL ) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - searchDuplicatedNumber" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    //point to character
    char *ptc;
    while( ( fgets(properties, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) ) != NULL ) {
        
        ptc = strstr(properties, search_Number);
        if( ptc != NULL) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    free(properties);
    return false;
}
//check if p.number meets all conditions
char* checkConditions(FILE *fp) {
    
    char continue_Question;
    char* phone_Number;
    char* which_Ordinal;

    phone_Number = (char*) malloc( MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH * sizeof(char) );
    which_Ordinal = (char*) malloc( 2 * sizeof(char) );
    if( phone_Number == NULL || which_Ordinal == NULL ) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - checkConditions" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    phone_Number = inputPhoneNumber();
    
    //check if it has character
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(phone_Number) - 1; ++i) {
        if( !isdigit( phone_Number[i] ) ){
            
            which_Ordinal = ordinals(i + 1);
            printf( "\nDetected error in input at %d%s position\nTry again\n"
                    , i + 1, which_Ordinal);
            //use recursion to make user provide correct input
            return checkConditions(fp);
        }
    }
    free(which_Ordinal);
    //check for duplicated number 
    if( searchDuplicatedNumber(fp, phone_Number) ) {
        printf( "\nPhone number -> %s is assigned to another contact!\n", phone_Number );
        //if user accidentally provided phone number that already exist in contacts
        //ask him if he wants to continue
        printf( "\nWould you like to continue?(Y/N) " );
        fgets(&continue_Question, 3, stdin);
        if(continue_Question == 'Y' || continue_Question == 'y') {
            return checkConditions(fp);
        }
        else {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return phone_Number;
}
//add ordinals to the number so it'd be grammatically correct 
char* ordinals( int i ) {

    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            return "st";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
            return "rd";
            break;
        default:
            return "th";
            break;
    }
}

//generate unique id for each contact
char* generateID() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    char* str_id = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    if( str_id == NULL ) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - generateID" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    sprintf(str_id, "%d", (rand() % (99999 - 10000 + 1)) + 10000);
    return str_id;
}

//files handling functions

//needed to look for duplicates
FILE *checkInAllContacts() {
    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( "All_Contacts.txt", "r");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        printf( "\nCould not open file\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    return fp;
}

//add new contact
void addNewContact( char* path, FILE *allContacts ) {
        
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(path, "w");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf( "\nUnable to create file\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    //get user input
    char* f_Name; 
    char* surname;
    char* ph_Number;
    //allocate memory
    f_Name = (char*) malloc(MAX_FNAME_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    surname = (char*) malloc(MAX_SNAME_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    ph_Number = malloc(MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH * sizeof(ph_Number));
    //check allocation
    if(f_Name == NULL || surname == NULL || ph_Number == NULL) {
        puts( "Memory allocation failed - addNewContact" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    //assign functions to variables
    f_Name = inputFirstName();
    surname = inputSurname();
    ph_Number = checkConditions(allContacts);
    printf( "\nGenerated id: %s\n", path );
    
    //add them to file
    fprintf( fp, "\nFirst name: %s", f_Name );
    fprintf( fp, "\nSurname: %s", surname );
    fprintf( fp, "\nPhone number: %s", ph_Number );
    fprintf( fp, "\nid: %s\n", path );

    //free memory and close file
    free(f_Name);
    free(surname);
    free(ph_Number);
    fclose(fp);
}

void addToAllContacts( char* path ) {
    
    FILE *fpS, *fpD;
    //buffer
    char putIn;
    
    fpS = fopen(path, "r");
    fpD = fopen("All_Contacts.txt", "a");

    if( fpS == NULL || fpD == NULL ) {
        puts( "File not found - appending" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    //add line to make it more readable
    fprintf(fpD, "\n----------------------------------------\n");
    
    //get text from source
    while ( (putIn = fgetc( fpS )) != EOF ) {
        //put it to destination file
        fputc(putIn, fpD);
    }
    fclose(fpS);
    fclose(fpD);
}

void showContactBasedOnPath( char* path ) {
    
    FILE* fp;
    char char_from_file;

    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    //check if exist
    if( !fp ) {
        puts( "\n**File not found**\n" );
        return;
    }

    while( (char_from_file = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN   "%c"   ANSI_COLOR_RESET , char_from_file );
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Probably some functions could be scaled into one, but tbh structure of this code is quite easy to understand, so that's why I did not change it. Also I'm aware of fact that if memory won't be allocated or file would be `NULL` then program is going to exit-crash. I'll change it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't built this with compiler warnings enabled.  That will give a lot of useful improvements (as will running under Valgrind).  I compiled with `gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion`, and that identified a number of problems.

---

> ```
> #define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
> #define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
> #define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
> #define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"
> ```

Completely non-portable - you don't to emit these escapes to a plain tty or a file.  Consider using a library that understands termcap database.

---

> ```
> char* inputFirstName();
> char* inputSurname();
> char* inputPhoneNumber();
> ```

These declarations would be better if they were prototypes:

```
char* inputFirstName(void);
char* inputSurname(void);
char* inputPhoneNumber(void);
```

---

> ```
> bool searchDuplicatedNumber( FILE *fp, char* search_Number );
> ```

Does this need to modify the contents of `search_Number`?  I think we could make that point to a non-modifiable string:

> ```
> bool searchDuplicatedNumber( FILE *fp, const char* search_Number );
> ```

`showContactBasedOnPath()` certanily should accept a `const char*`, as it's passed a string literal in `main()`.

`char* ordinals(int i)` should return a `const char*`, since we can't modify the string literals it returns.

---

Have you tested `ordinals()` with a reasonable set of inputs?  I think it will happily claim that "21th" is correct instead of "21st".

---

> ```
> phone_Number = (char*) malloc( MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH * sizeof(char) );
> which_Ordinal = (char*) malloc( 2 * sizeof(char) );
> if( phone_Number == NULL || which_Ordinal == NULL ) {
>     puts( "Memory allocation failed - checkConditions" );
>     exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
> }
> ```

Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is pointless, as `char` is the basic unit of measurement, making its size equal to 1.

Casting the returned pointer from `malloc()` is at best pointless and at worst actively harmful.

If one allocation succeeds and the other fails, we leak memory (although this is currently mitigated by calling `exit()`, we'll probably want to change to returning a null pointer so the calling code can choose how best to handle it).

```
phone_Number = malloc(MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH);
which_Ordinal = malloc(2);
if (!phone_Number || !which_Ordinal) {
    free(phone_Number);
    free(which_Ordinal);
    return NULL;
}
```

---

> ```
> char putIn;
> while ( (putIn = fgetc( fpS )) != EOF ) {
> ```

Converting to `char` before testing equality with `EOF` is wrong.  We need to test before we truncate:

```
int putIn;
while ((putIn = fgetc(fpS)) != EOF) {
```

---

We're comparing signed and unsigned here:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < strlen(phone_Number) - 1; ++i) {
> ```

Not only that, but we're calling `strlen()` every time around the loop.

```
const size_t phone_len = strlen(phone_Number) - 1;
for(size_t i = 0;  i < phone_len;  ++i) {
```

It's not clear why we omit the last character here.

> ```
>     if( !isdigit( phone_Number[i] ) ){
> ```

Oops - `isdigit((unsigned char)phone_Number[i])`, because `<ctype.h>` functions expect *positive* integer input (or `EOF`).

---

> ```
>      free(which_Ordinal);
> ```

That's invalid if `which_Ordinal = ordinals(i + 1);` was executed, as we've overwritten the pointer with one that didn't come from `malloc()` (and can no longer access the allocated memory - we've leaked that).

---

There's loads of buffer overruns.  For example:

> ```
> char* str_id = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
> if( str_id == NULL ) {
>     puts( "Memory allocation failed - generateID" );
>     exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
> }
> sprintf(str_id, "%d", (rand() % (99999 - 10000 + 1)) + 10000);
> ```

We're writing 5 digits and a null character to an alloctation of size 4.  Allocate the correct size buffer, and consider `snprintf()` to help you (though that shouldn't really be needed, and Valgrind can help).

---

Don't call `srand()` more than once in a program.  Call it at the start of `main()`, and then trust it.

Answer (score 3):

## General Observations

Performance could be improved by reading all the contacts into memory at the start of the program and writing all the contacts back to a file at the end of the program. Searching a file for a duplicate is more time consuming then searching memory. This does however depend on the number of contacts being maintained.

Using a struct that represents a contact would be beneficial, by grouping all of the data for one contact into one variable with fields.

The list of function prototypes at the top of the program can be avoided if the functions are in the correct order and `main()` is the last function in the file. This reduces the amount of code (and possible bugs) in a file. In this case the only function that needs to be moved besides `main()` is `char* ordinals(int i)`.

## Declaration of the `main()` Function

Since the code completely ignores `argC` and `argV` the declaration of `main()` could be:

```
int main(void) {}
```

## Inconsistent Indentation in the `main()` function

The contents of the `do while` loop are not properly indented, this makes the code harder to read and understand.

## Complexity of the `main()` function

The function `main()` is too complex (does too much). As programs grow in size the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

Specifically either the `do while` loop or the contents of the `do while` loop should be moved into a function that returns an integer value. Case `q` should use `return` rather than `exit()`. Case `1` and case `3` should call functions to simplify the switch statement.

## Program Return Value Consistency

Since the code is already using the system defined constants `EXIT _FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` the `main()` function should return these values as well.

## Use the System Defined File Pointer `stderr` to Report Errors

Rather than reporting errors to standard output there is a special output file called `stderr` for reporting errors. This provides a separate output stream for errors. When redirecting standard output to a file this special stream will still report errors to the console or terminal where the program is running.

Usage:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR MESSAGE CONTENTS");
```

## Memory Leaks

The function `void addNewContact(char* path, FILE* allContacts)` is leaking memory, first it allocates memory for `f_Name`, `surname` and `ph_Number` and then it calls `inputFirstName()` and `inputSurname()` which allocates memory for `f_Name` and `surname` again. This is throwing away the first allocation without freeing it. The first allocation is never used.

## Usage of `fgets()`

Rather than allocating a buffer and then reading it using `fgets()` Creat a fixed sized array of characters large enough to contain a whole line, call `fgets()` with that buffer and then allocate as much space as necessary for the string using either `strlen()` or the number of characters read in that `fgets()` returns.

```
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t charCount = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    if (charCount > MAX_FNAME_LENGTH)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "The first name %s is too long, please limit the first name to %d characters", buffer, MAX_FNAME_LENGTH);
    }
```

Always check user input for possible errors.

Answer (score 3):

### Input overrun

`option` is one character; so why do you write `3` here?

```
fgets( &option, 3, stdin );
```

### Implicit string concatenation

```
printf(     "\n\t\t***Contact management system***\n1. Add new contact\n2. Show all contacts\n3. Show specific contact\n*Press 'q' to exit*\n"      );
```

is more legible as

```
printf(
    "\n"
    "\t\t***Contact management system***\n"
    "1. Add new contact\n"
    "2. Show all contacts\n"
    "3. Show specific contact\n"
    "*Press 'q' to exit*\n"
);
```

### Fixed buffers

Your code would be greatly simplified by replacing your dynamic allocation for every string that uses these lengths:

```
#define ID_LENGTH 5
#define MAX_FNAME_LENGTH 16
#define MAX_SNAME_LENGTH 32
#define MAX_PHONENUMBER_LENGTH 15
```

with fixed-size buffers. These buffers can exist inside of a `struct` that @pacmaninbw has already described, reducing your `malloc` calls significantly.

Comment: I've to use size = 3 in fgets(), because at the end of string there is terminating NULL and I think 'Enter' takes one part of size since after pressing Enter it loops twice (when size = 2) but when it's assigned to 3 then there's no problem. I did like you suggested and changed the printf(). About this allocation. I thought about creating struct with variables that has fixed buffers which are pointing to functions, but did not know how to do this and later just forgot about that. Thanks for advice

Comment: OK; well if you expect more than one byte you're going to need to write to a larger variable.